# Theos not compiling with Arm64

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, arm64

I am trying to package a Jailbreak Tweak using Theos on Windows 8.1 (64bit). If I do not specify Arm64 it compiles fine and works on my iPhone 5. However not my 6s. The console says a big error which I don't understand. Any help trying to get this tweak to compile with 64bit architecture would be great.

Makefile:

```
ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
test_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = Forton
Forton_FILES = Tweak.xm

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

SUBPROJECTS += fortonprefs
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/aggregate.mk
```

Error Log:

```
$ make package
/home/AbbottL/forton/theos/makefiles/targets/Cygwin/iphone.mk:38: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak Forton...
Linking tweak Forton...
ld: warning: ignoring file /home/AbbottL/forton/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o, missing required architecture arm64 in file /home/AbbottL/forton/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /home/AbbottL/forton/theos/lib/libsubstrate.dylib, file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /home/AbbottL/forton/theos/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_MSHookMessageEx", referenced from:
  _logosLocalInit() in Tweak.xm.91812798.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
armv7-apple-darwin11-clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
/home/AbbottL/forton/theos/makefiles/instance/library.mk:27: recipe for target 'obj/Forton.dylib.1b5b9d6a.unsigned' failed
make[2]: *** [obj/Forton.dylib.1b5b9d6a.unsigned] Error 1
/home/AbbottL/forton/theos/makefiles/instance/library.mk:19: recipe for target 'internal-library-all_' failed
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
/home/AbbottL/forton/theos/makefiles/master/rules.mk:54: recipe for target 'Forton.all.tweak.variables' failed
make: *** [Forton.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Using ios 8.1 SDK

Comment: Well, there's a warning from... something... that apparently some configuration or whatnot will result in ARMv7-only binaries of... something... being built, followed later by a linker getting cross because it can only find ARMv7 binaries for something. That much seems clear enough, unfortunately the rest of the question is iOS stuff which _I_ don't understand... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by swapping libsustrate file to a later version.